# XML detect debug mode

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, debugging

I know that programatically I can use

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
  // do something for a debug build
}
```

However, what I'd like to do is show a watermark when in debug mode. Is there a way to do something similar to this in the XML files?

Comment: No, you cant do that, at least not easily, theres no conditional statement for xml files, maybe you can find a way to make the app use the watermarked xmls like it does for different density but im unsure. you should just do it by code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible now with the [Data Binding Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding).

First, you have to define a variable for the `BuildConfig` object:

```
<data>
  <import type="android.view.View" />

  <variable
    name="buildConfig"
    type="your.app.domain.BuildConfig"/>
</data>
```

Then just use it like this:

```
<ImageView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:visibility="@{buildConfig.DEBUG ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}">
```

Comment: After over five years :D

Comment: Actually, the data binding is available for some years. Unfortunately, I didn't see this question earlier. :)

Comment: As a note, this only works for layout files.

Comment: didn't work till i add  buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }  in build.gradle