# How to use data-binding in Dialog?

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding, android-databinding

I am having trouble in implementing databinding in a Dialog. Is it possible?

Below is my xml.

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="olaBooking"
        type="com.example.myapp.viewmodels.ViewModel" />
</data>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:padding="15dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:text="OLA Cab Booked !"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="start|center"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:text="Car Details" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/driverName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@{olaBooking.driverName}" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/carModel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@{olaBooking.getCarName}" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/carNo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@{olaBooking.getCabNo}" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/eta"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@{olaBooking.getEta}" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to bind the above layout in a Dialog. How is it possible? Below is my java code i tried but it's not working

```
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_ola_booking_confirmed);
    DialogOlaBookingConfirmedBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(dialog.getContext()),
            R.layout.dialog_ola_booking_confirmed,
            (ViewGroup) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cv),
            false);
    ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel(this, event.olaBooking);
```

Answer (score 101, accepted):

It is possible to use databinding in a Dialog, first to get the binding working on your Dialog you should inflate it first and pass it to the setContentView like this.

```
DialogOlaBookingConfirmedBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(getContext()), R.layout. dialog_ola_booking_confirmed, null, false);
setContentView(binding.getRoot());
```

Then you can pass the viewModel:

```
binding.setViewModel(new ViewModel(this, event.olaBooking));
```

And now you can see it working.

Comment: dialog is not properly showing when set using binding and it works with normal way

Comment: this made my bottomsheet dialog stretched to whole screen

Comment: worked for me. thanks. how to hide dialog from viewmodel now?

Comment: To hide it make a MutableLiveData val of Bool and subscribe to it inside the FragmentDialog

Comment: Which lifecycleOwner to we set to the binding?

Comment: How can I adapt this to working with a popup, where my popup has an include? The popup is triggered from a button event `public void onClick(View c)`

Answer (score 45):

#### You should not use `DataBindingUtil` for generated classes as said in **[Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/DataBindingUtil)**

You should use **generated binding class's** **`inflate`** & **`bind`** method (`MyDialogBinding.inflate`).

```
public void showDialog(final Context context) {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    MyDialogBinding binding = MyDialogBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context));
    dialog.setContentView(binding.getRoot());
    dialog.show();
}
```

#### Can it be simpler? No!

**[Binding Document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/DataBindingUtil)** says for `DataBindingUtil` class's **`inflate method`**.

> Use this version only if layoutId is unknown in advance. Otherwise,
>   use the generated Binding's inflate method to ensure type-safe
>   inflation.
>       DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(getContext()),R.layout.my_info_dialog_layout, null, false);

**This is like finding binding generated class, when we have class already.**

#### Instead use this

```
MyDialogBinding binding = MyDialogBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context));
```

or if you want make another class.

```
public class MyDialog extends Dialog {
    public MyDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MyDialogBinding binding = MyDialogBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(getContext()));
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It's also nicer because it passes fewer arguments to `inflate()`.

Comment: any suggestions if we want to make it generic and move it to base dialog then i guess we can use  databindingutil only ?

Answer (score 35):

Here is a full example of an AlertDialog with Databinding:

```java
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;


public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {

    private static final String KEY_MY_INFO = "KEY_MY_INFO";

    private String myInfo;

    public static MyDialog newInstance(String myInfo) {
        MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(KEY_MY_INFO, myInfo);
        dialog.setArguments(bundle);
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myInfo = getArguments().getString(KEY_MY_INFO);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
        
        MyInfoBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(getContext()),
                R.layout.my_info_dialog_layout, null, false);

        binding.setMyInfo(myInfo);

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(activity, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle)
                .setView(binding.getRoot())
                .create();
    }

}
```

Comment: Sometimes people just post their answers without a context. So somebody (me for example) may have no clue on where to put the code that worked. Thank you for posting a full solution :).

Comment: @MarekM. yep, just like this guy https://stackoverflow.com/a/66025950/2445763

Answer (score 17):

You can do the same without calling getRoot().

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_delete_confirmation, null, false);

mBinding = DialogDeleteConfirmationBinding.bind(view);

mBinding.setViewModel(viewModel);

builder.setView(view);

builder.create();
```

Answer (score 12):

```
  mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(getContext()), R.layout.dialog_select, null, false);
    setContentView(mBinding.getRoot());
    SelectDialogBean data = new SelectDialogBean();
    mBinding.setData(data);
```

Comment: When applying this solution, I noticed the suggested `LayoutInflater.from(getContext())` gives me a different theme inside the dialog than before using data binding. I ended up using the `LayoutInflater` the dialog provides like so: `dialog.getLayoutInflater()` or `LayoutInflater.from(dialog.getContext())`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to extend `Dialog`, another possible solution could be:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this); // where "this" is the context

YourClassNameBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(dialog.getLayoutInflater(), R.layout.your_layout, null, false);
binding.setYourData(yourData);

dialog.setContentView(binding.getRoot());
dialog.show();
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

## If your dialog shrink, Try this

I tried @Dullahan's answer, however the dialog seemed to shrink strangely.
So I tried another ways, finally found solution.

```xml
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="500dp">

        <!-- ... -->

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

```kotlin
class CustomDialog(context: Context) : Dialog(context) {
    private lateinit var binding: CustomDialogBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog)
        binding = CustomDialogBinding.bind(findViewById(R.id.root))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use activity inside of context for DialogFragment.

The problem when you use databinding in DialogFragment is theme is not respect to dark mode colors. If you have problem with this use `LayoutInflater.from(activity)` inside of `LayoutInflater.from(context)`

Answer (score -1):

`val bottomViewBinding :AddProductNoPositionBottomPupUpBinding = AddProductNoPositionBottomPupUpBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) bottomSheetDialog = BottomSheetDialog(this , R.style.BottomSheetDialoTheme) bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(bottomViewBinding.root) bottomSheetDialog.show() bottomViewBinding.productDataBinding = product`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).