# How to use Databinding with DialogFragment

Tags: java, android-databinding

In my app I have an `ElementListFragment` of items represented by a code object `Element`. I've data-bound these elements to the list and they display the correct information.
However, to continue filling in the information in each item I put a button on each element that shows a `Dialog` with additional fields.
But when the `Dialog` opens the fields are all blank (where one at least ought to be filled) and any fields I fill don't save the data (and don't effect changes on the list).

Appart from the values not being bound (displayed or written), the application works fine. I've essentially tried multiple variations of the sugestions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967868/how-to-use-data-binding-in-dialog). Here is the code:

```
public class ElementDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
        private Element mElement;
        private Dialog dialog;

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_element, null);

            final DialogSkillelementBinding binding = DialogElementBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(getContext()));

            builder.setView(v)
                    // Add action buttons
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.save, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            //this was just an attempt to make it work
                            binding.executePendingBindings();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

            TextView Title = v.findViewById(R.id.skill_e_dialog_title);
            Title.setText(ResourceLocator.getSkillName(mElement.getSkill()));

            dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.setContentView(binding.getRoot());

            binding.setElement(mElement);
            binding.executePendingBindings();

            return dialog;
        }
    }
```

When debuging I've confirmed that `mElement` is correctly attributed, however it's also bound to the list shown beneath the dialog. The title is also displayed correctly.

Is there a problem double-binding an object?

Are some of the steps on the function maybe out of order?

Is the DialogBuilder somehow incompatible with databinding?

Answer (score 1):

You should set `LyfecycleOwner` for your binding class for data updating.

```
binding.setLifecycleOwner(requireActivity())
```